# Ajax Url being overridden

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am making an AJAX request onchange from a rails app. The function is a very simple PUT request:

```
function quantityChange(id, val) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_items/' + id,
        method: "PUT",
        data: {quantity: val},
        success: function() {}
    })
}
```

My issue is the URL that is being called by the request is `http://localhost:3004/` and not `http://localhost:3004/cart_items/:id`.

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and have tested the snippet in JSBin. Everything works as expected there but in the Rails app it tries to call the root hostname. If I change the url to `cart_items` + `id` without the forward slash the concatenation and url come out almost correct `http:localhost:3004/cart_items:id` minus the forward slash that is needed.

I do not understand why the application is defaulting to the root hostname when providing ajax with this url.

[image: Error in console]

Comment: sounds like something going on server side

Comment: Try changing the url to `'/cart_items/' + id`

Comment: Have tried that. Same issue

Comment: Try that along with `type: "PUT"` instead of  `method: "PUT"`

Comment: Shouldn't that `$.put` be `$.ajax` ?

Comment: @Pavan Still no luck. I am posting a picture of the error. Also sorry it was a $.ajax I also tried $.put

Comment: Do you see any error in the server log other than that of console?

Comment: Have you tried the whole absolute url?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was I needed to set my CSRF Token. Since I did not have one the request was being redirected to the root hostname.

```
function quantityChange(id, val) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cart_items/' + id,
        type: "PUT",
        data: {quantity: val},
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', 'token');},
        success: function() {}
    })
}
```